# failed to get data from my contract using the navbar (web3 react hooks async function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, web3js

I'm trying to build My first react Dapp! The problem I encounter is the data doesn't load only when I'm refreshing the page instead of navigating with the navbar !
for example when I navigate to profile the section using web3 doesn't load but when I refresh the page, all the data is filled correctly and all works fine
here's my code of the component which is call the section using web3 (it's the profile section) :

```
function Home() {
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [account, setAccounts] = useState(null);
  const [contract, setContract] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {

    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        console.log("ok1");
        const web3 = await getWeb3();
        console.log("ok2");
        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
        const deployedNetwork = CVStorageContract.networks[networkId];
        const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
          CVStorageContract.abi,
          deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,
        );
        setAccounts(accounts);
        setContract(instance);
        const response = await instance.methods.getProfileDetails(accounts[0]).call();
        setProfile(response);

      } catch (error) {
        // Catch any errors for any of the above operations.
        alert(
          `Failed to load web3, accounts, or contract. `,
        );
        console.error(error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false)
      }
    }
    fetchData();

  });

return (  
<>
{loading ? <div>Loading ... </div> : <div className="layout-content">         
            <Profile profile={profile} account={account} contract={contract} page="home" />
      </div>}

    </>
  );
```

it stuck in loading when I navigate using the navbar and the console only show " ok1 " (which is the first `console.log` without any error message

and here's the getWeb3.js

```
import Web3 from "web3";

const getWeb3 = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Wait for loading completion to avoid race conditions with web3 injection timing.
    window.addEventListener("load", async () => {
      // Modern dapp browsers...
      if (window.ethereum) {
        const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        try {
          // Request account access if needed
          await window.ethereum.enable();
          // Accounts now exposed
          resolve(web3);
        } catch (error) {
          reject(error);
        }
      }
      // Legacy dapp browsers...
      else if (window.web3) {
        // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider.
        const web3 = window.web3;
        console.log("Injected web3 detected.");
        resolve(web3);
      }
      // Fallback to localhost; use dev console port by default...
      else {
        const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
          "http://127.0.0.1:8545"
        );
        const web3 = new Web3(provider);
        console.log("No web3 instance injected, using Local web3.");
        resolve(web3);
      }
    });
  });

export default getWeb3;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need pass an empty array to `useEffect` in your Home component to render each time that the component render, if you dont pass it, the function just execute one time

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
     //...code
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: Same problem nothing changes! It render when i  navigate to it ! And the proof is that the console shows the first console.log